# Why am i getting (Operation: read, User: 2) as admin?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I've installed a very basic custom module (contains one tiny model) and when i try to use it in a form i get the following error:

> Sorry, you are not allowed to access this document. Please contact
>   your system administrator if you think this is an error.
>
> (Document model: {model name here}) - (Operation: read, User: 2)

While i'm logged in as admin and have developer mode on (should be irrelevant). I haven't altered anything in the security directory that was generated by `odoo-bin scaffold ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Odoo 12 the user OdooBot user (ID 1) is now the super user and doesn't need rights explicitly. But user Admin (ID 2) needs them now. I bet your tiny module does not have any right definition (ir.model.access.csv) in it.

So either implement rights or for testing purposes switch to OdooBot (developer mode context menu).

Comment: It did have the default one, i read somewhere that removing the group field would enable it globally (which would be best) this is for the location thingy you answered for me earlier

Comment: Yes `ir.model.access` without group assigns the given rights (read, write, delete and/or create) to every Odoo user).

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is having similar problem and have properly configured security definition then check if you spelled your reference model right. In may case I was referencing `res.user` (which does not exists) instead of `res.users` and got that error